# How can i confirm transaction in geth from other peer of blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, cpp-ethereum, ethereumj

I have a query , I have create a private blockchain in which one geth node1 is use for transaction taking and other one(node2) is for mining .They are peered with each other and perfectly synchronizing. But when i am doing so every thing is fine but the transaction are not conforming . I have to run miner on node1 them it is confirming .

setup node1

```
geth --datadir firstserver  --networkid 1300 --port 30303 --rpcport 8000 --rpc  --maxpeers 3 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --nat=any --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner" --bootnodes enode://bcf91ae94b3ab1505d1607c2b936422da23d6a67b5cbdf4eb6f1bc7cc78ada47bfdea80e10b56f99e35b380e9af1b8ff3f6ee334e2b210db8ae97c539cbc2414@127.0.0.1:30304 --rpc   --rpccorsdomain "*" --targetgaslimit 210060000000   console
```

setup node2

```
geth --datadir secondserver  --networkid 1300 --port 30304 --rpcport 8001 --rpc  --maxpeers 3 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --nat=any  --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner" --etherbase 0x31b4138e4594ece4d8f900db0589fa319b694c8e --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --targetgaslimit 210060000000   console
```

and addPeers in both the server . And i started mining (miner.start(1)) in  second node the first on is importing the data perfectly . then i create contract in first node by web3 and it is not generating contract address until ii start mining in node1

NOTE: coinbase is same , genesis code is same

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you set up your private blockchain?
It seems it is a know issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2769

Comment: @FrenchieiSverige edit the question.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given in the last post of the link that I gave you?

Comment: do you run the peers in the same hardware(pc)?